# Asyncio on long running task

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I just learned async with python 3.5 yesterday.

here is what I want to accomplish today.

```
import asyncio  
import time
import requests

async def foo():
    """Some Long Running Taks"""
    requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41301031/asyncio-on-long-running-task")
    print("foo")

async def bar():
    """Some Quick Task"""
    print("bar")

while True:
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(foo(), bar()))
    loop.close()
    time.sleep(2)

#Expected output
"""
>>>bar
>>>bar
>>>bar
>>>bar
>>>bar
>>>foo
and so on
"""
```

Is this possible using python async/await?

Comment: `run_until_complete` is blocking. The next iteration of your while loop won't begin until everything you gather havs completed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code:

1. requests does not support asyncio, use [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) instead.
2. Your couroutines will run only when the loop is running:  Call `loop.run_until_complete()` only once in your code, and schedule many (short or long) tasks using `await` (or `asycio.ensure_future()` or `loop.create_task()`).

Here is an example doing something similar to what you were trying to do:

```
# make sure to run `pip install aiohttp` first!!!

import asyncio

import aiohttp


async def slow_fetch(delay):
    url = "http://httpbin.org/delay/{}".format(delay)
    print("Getting ", url)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            text = await resp.text()
    print("Got {}, {} chars".format(url, len(text)))


async def quick_loop():
    print("enter quick_loop")
    for i in range(10):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("quick_loop", i)
    print("exit quick_loop")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
    slow_fetch(3),
    slow_fetch(4),
    quick_loop(),
))
loop.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this comment, this is still working for 2022 <3

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better approach to the `ensure_future` / `create_task`:
USE A DECORATOR

```
def async_wrap(func):
    @wraps(func)
    async def run(*args, loop=None, executor=None, **kwargs):
        if loop is None:
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        pfunc = partial(func, *args, **kwargs)
        return await loop.run_in_executor(executor, pfunc)

    return run
```

Now if you have a long running function like some function that uses `requests` you can do this:

```
@async_wrap
def long_running_function():
    return requests.get(_URL)
```

Answer (score 1):

your `time.sleep()` is blocking; you need to use `asyncio.sleep()`.

and why do you run your `loop` inside `while True`?

also note that `asyncio` will only help speedup io-bound tasks (e.g. get data from the net). it will not help you speed up cpu-bound tasks. for that you need [threads](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html?highlight=threading#module-threading) or [multiplrocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing).

seeing that you have updated your question, here a small update in my answer: also `requests` is blocking and does not play nice with `asyncio`. [`aiohttp`](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is similiar in its functionality but does play nice with `asyncio`

Comment: time.sleep() is just to show that this is long running task. You can replace it with any web requests.

Comment: no, you can not. if your web requests can run asynchronously (e.g. from [aiohttp](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) they will yield control back to the caller. you can not mock that with `time.sleep` (but with `await asyncio.sleep`). if you use a blocking call (e.g. `requests` which can not do async for now) then ok, that would be the same. but then there is no point to use `asyncio`.

Comment: Ok. So it's not straight forward like node

Comment: I was expecting that if I write async function, everything inside a function is asynchronous.

Comment: sorry, no. only coroutines will help. the functions you call must be programmed to yield control back to the caller. otherwise they will block. Luciano Ramalho's book Fluent Python has an excellent chapter about coroutines and asyncio... just in case.

Comment: Thanks. I will surely Read.